# extracting multi-line from file by using regular expression on python

Tags: python, regex, data-extraction

I Would like to extract the lines that between  {"befor " 17}, {"androidID 
 and "{"After ", 16}, {"37abc5afce16b6www03", 17}" on my file by using regular expression on python

I have text as follow:

```
      [pid  3342] 12:13:44 pread64(6,"res/color/hint_foreground_material_light.xml", 44, 377177) = 44
      [pid  3342] 12:13:44 mmap(NULL, 597, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 6, 0x5c000) = 0x7f7754c000
      [pid  3342] 12:13:44 munmap(0x7f7754c000, 597) = 0
      [pid  3342] 12:13:44 *writev(4, [{" hZZ  v;", 11}, {" ", 1}, {"befor " 17}, {"androidID ", 10}], 4) = 39*
      [pid  3342] 12:13:44 getuid()           = 11811
      [pid  3342] 12:13:44 getuid()           = 11811
      [pid  3342] 12:13:44 ioctl(11, 0xc0306201, 0x7fc52d8fb0) = 0
      [pid  3342] 12:13:44 ioctl(11, 0xc0306201, 0x7fc52d9180) = 0
      [pid  3342] 12:13:44 writev(3, [{"l ", 7}, {"hZZ ;", 11}, {" ", 1}, {"After ", 16}, {"37abc5afce16b6www03", 17}], 5)= 52
      [pid  3342] 12:13:44 getuid()           = 11811
       ...
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have to use regular expression? If not you could just iterate over the file and start saving if the line contains the ' {"befor " 17}, {"androidID' and stop if the line contains the end value.

Comment: The problem for your approach is that sometimes I have  "before" and androidID in not  single

Comment: @kaloon, post the final expected result

Answer (score 0):

Try this one `r"(?m)^.*?\{\"befor[ ]\"[ ]17\},[ ]\{\"androidID.*[\S\s]+?^.*?\{\"After[ ]\",[ ]16\},[ ]\{\"37abc5afce16b6www03\",[ ]17\}.*"`

https://regex101.com/r/fyPZpq/1

```
 (?m)
 ^ .*? \{"befor [ ] " [ ] 17\}, [ ] \{"androidID .* 
 [\S\s]+? 
 ^ .*? \{"After [ ] ", [ ] 16\}, [ ] \{"37abc5afce16b6www03", [ ] 17\} .*
```